# Contentful Rails Test if Object is Empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, contentful

```
p entry # <Contentful::Entry[item] id='3oXocy0iJX8ksdfe435RjWjE'>
i = entry.image
p i.present? # true
p i.nil? # false
p i.respond_to?(:url) # true
p i.url # undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
p i # undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm pulling an item from Contenful CMS and trying to render it in Rails.  My content admin managed to delete the image (the field is actually called "image") on the entry, thereby causing the render to break.  The code above is me trying to test for a missing image so I can skip rendering the section and not break my website.

As you can see, this is mindnumbingly insane.  Rails says the entry is there (it is), it says it's not nil, then immediately below it throws an error for nil:NilClass.

The last line is probably the most interesting - even if I just try to print or inspect "i" I still get the error as if I'm trying to access the url attribute.  I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

Comment: What's the stack trace from the NoMethodError that `i.url` raises? Perhaps `i` is delegating the `url` method to something else.

Comment: @muistooshort the stack trace is very short:

```app/views/shared/sections/_item.html.erb:11
app/views/home/index.html.erb:6
app/views/home/index.html.erb:2:in 'each'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:2```

All that's happening is the code is looping through content types and rendering partials and passing in each entry.

`<%= render "shared/sections/#{content_type}", entry: s %>`

This all works fine unless the image is missing on an entry....

Comment: What if you do it in the console? Might get a better trace there. If this is an emergency, you could catch the exception and ignore it while you clean up the mess.

Comment: @muistooshort I was able to get in there with Pry, but of course now she fixed the broken image.  I'll try to recreate the error state and circle back.  Thanks for your help so far!